# c++ dereference a pointer to an iterator

Tags: c++, pointers, stl, iterator, dereference

This question is related to another question on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51880506/why-is-it-necessary-to-put-a-pointer-in-parenthesis-when-using-the-operator).

In the c++ code below is `*input_` an iterator or a pointer to an iterator?

So `node_insert()` returns an iterator and assigns it to `*input_`. This makes me think that `*input_` is not a pointer to an iterator because how can you assign an iterator to a pointer to an iterator.

At this point the iterator is pointing to an element in the graph container. Is this correct?

Is `(*input_)` dereferencing the iterator (or a pointer to an iterator)?

I can't understand why the braces are necessary around the iterator to invoke the method `setOutputTensor()`.

I'm a bit confused.

```
Data::OpListIterator *input_;
*input_ = dataGraph_.node_insert(allocator_.make_owner<op::Input>(shape, dType, order, opName));
(*input_)->setOutputTensor(outputTensor, 0);
```

Comment: There's a lot of unspecified types in that code.  Can you make it self-contained (i.e. a [mcve])?  Doing that will help you get better answers.

Comment: "I can't understand why the braces are necessary" is the same question you asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51880506/why-is-it-necessary-to-put-a-pointer-in-parenthesis-when-using-the-operator . Please avoid more than one question per question and please avoid to ask the same question twice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your are using

```
*input_->setOutputTensor(outputTensor, 0);
```

it is equal to

```
*input_*.setOutputTensor(outputTensor, 0);
```

so in this case `input_` is dereferenced (which results in an iterator) then the function `setOutputTensor` is called on the iterator and will result in an error.

If you are using `(*input_)` the pointer to the iterator is dereferenced first and than dereferenced by `->` again. So the main difference using the braces, is the order of dereferencing.